Composition of 2 bijective function is bijective
Its a theorem that composition of 2 bijective function is bijective but here I have taken an example where composition of 2 bijective function is not bijective. Where am I going wrong ?
$f:${$a,b,c,d$} ---> {$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \eta$}$:f=${$(a,\alpha),(b,\beta),(c,\gamma),(d,\eta)$}
$g:${$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \eta,\delta$} ---> {$1,2,3,4,5$}$:g=${$(\alpha,1),(\beta,2),(\gamma,3),(\eta,4),(\delta,5)$}
now both $f$ and $g$ are bijective but
$gof:${$a,b,c,d$} ---> {$1,2,3,4,5$}$: gof =${$(a,1),(b,2),(c,3),(d,4)$}
is not surjective.

This makes no sense.  In order to compose to functions, the codomain of one has to be the domain of the other.

but the condition is that the range of one has to be the subset of domain of the other.

@ca_100 no, that's not the condition.  That sort of composition is old and outdated (for reasons like this).

Between $g$ and $f$, there's an inclusion map $$\iota:{\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \eta}\to {\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \eta, \delta}$$ to match the codomain of $f$ and the domain of $g$, and so the whole composition is $g\circ \iota \circ f$. This inclusion map $\iota$ is not surjective and not bijective.

@Randall: "old and outdated"? In the standard set-theoretic representation of functions, the codomain of a function is essentially left unspecified and it's simply false that the composition of two bijections is a bijection.

Please tell us what book or notes you are working from. There is a lot of confusion in the comments because people are making assumptions about the context.

@peterwhy: you are making assumptions about the context. Your intermediate function $\iota$ would be unnecessary in the standard set-theoretic world.

@RobArthan yes, old and outdated. Modern mathematics embraces the categorical point of view, one of whose basic tenets is that you can only compose composable morphisms. The fact that composition can be defined in an "untyped" way in sets because functions are also sets is an implementation detail, and thinking of composition in these terms is bound to generate confusions like the OP's.

@NaïmFavier: the OP is writing functions as set displays. That strongly suggests to me that the categorical point of view (for which I have considerable respect as an algebraic topologist, turned computer scientist turned logician)  is irrelevant here. Please don't be dogmatic about what "modern mathematics" is: the only reasonable thing to say is that it's a broad church and we should all try to be sufficiently mathematically mature to recognise what is approprriate in a given situation. The OP here should really supply some more context to clarify the sources they reference.

The theorem that asserts that $g \circ f$ is bijective when $f,g$ are bijective applies provided that codomain of $f$ is identical to the domain of $g$, which is not the case in the example you provided.

But as far as my book goes, it says that of composite of 2 functions say $fog$ is defined when range of $g$ is a subset of domain of $f$

This is precisely the problem with defining composition that way.

@ca_100 $f \circ g$ being defined is different than when the theorem applies. What I tried to explain is that, for the theorem to be valid, you need the two to be identical. If they are not identical, then you might be able to define the composition, but still, will not be able to apply the theorem.
